# Plotting discontinuous function in MATLAB/Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have not been able to find this around the web or in the docs, though that may be my due to my own incompetence. I plot functions in Octave by putting the x's in an x vector and the y's in an fx vector and then calling `plot(x,fx)`. However, since the function has huge vertical jumps it creates unwanted vertical lines. I can do `plot(x,fx,".")`, but that makes the line very thick. How can I plot a discontinuous function with a thin line?

Comment: can you share your plot? i don't understand why `plot(x,fx,'.')` makes the line thick? it would technically avoid plotting lines altogether and leave dots only.

Comment: if the points causing huge vertical jumps are outliers then have you considered removing them altogether? there could be several ways of doing that, like by setting all the points above a threshold to NaN ...

Comment: No, its more like a piecewise function

Comment: I agree with @PacificStickler .  I don't see why you can't just simply put `NaN` in between the discontinuities.  A plot that shows what your problems are would be nice too.

Comment: an example plot would be helpful

Comment: @PacificStickler I'm done working for the day, I'll put one up tomorrow.

Comment: If you are otherwise happy with `plot(x,fx,'.')` (i.e. you want a series of dots without a connecting line), you can decrease the marker size (which is what makes your "line" very thick): `plot(x,fx,'.', 'MarkerSize',1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Octave, you can decrease the size of the marker like this:

```
x = 0:0.1:100;
fx = rand(length(x), 1)';
plot(x, fx, ".", "markersize", 1)
```

Comment: This was already proposed in the comments. Apparently the OP is not satisfied with this alternative.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry, been away a few days! This is actually precisely what I need! I upvoted that comment right now.

Answer (score 4):

You could insert `nan`s at your discontinuities.
A way to automate this could be to look for large difference quotients:

```
x = linspace(0,30,1000);
y = ceil(cos(x));
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
dxLimit = 10;
x = x(:).'; y = y(:).';
discontinuities = (abs(diff(y)./diff(x))>dxLimit);
x = [x; nan(1,length(x))];
y = [y; nan(1,length(y))];
x(2*find(~discontinuities)) = [];
y(2*find(~discontinuities)) = [];
x = x(:).'; y = y(:).';
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
plot(x,y,'-'); ylim(ylim+[-0.3,+0.3]);
```

Comment: I was looking for a way just plot points instead of plotting connected lines. The problem I had was that when you just use the plot(...,...,".") option you get a really thick line.

Comment: @RenéG: Well if you just wanted to plot points, your question: *"How can I plot a discontinuous function with a thin line?"* might be a bit off then...

Comment: @knedlsepp - This may be a case of [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)