# How to graph the function in matlab?

Tags: function, matlab, plot, graph, ode

I have the following `2n*π`-periodic function `F(x) = sin(x/n)`  and I need to graph the `dx/dt = γ - F(x)` on the segment from `0` to `2pi`. So it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po002.png). I tried to do it matlab this way:

```
gamma = 1.01;
n=3;
[t,phi] = ode45(@(t,x)gamma-sin(x/n), [0,400], pi);
[t1,phi1] = ode45(@(t,x)gamma-sin(x/n), [112,400], 0);
[t2,phi2] = ode45(@(t,x)gamma-sin(x/n), [231,250], 0);
figure();  
plot(t, phi, 'k', t1, phi1, 'k', t2, phi2, 'k');
ylim([0 2*pi]);
yticks([0 pi 2*pi]);
yticklabels(["0" "\pi" "2\pi"]);
grid on; grid minor;
title('\itsin(x/n)')
```

but I only got [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROnjN.png). So there the lines are not transferred, but "begin anew". does anyone here know how to do that?

Comment: What is the use of the reduction to this interval? Just for a compact plot, or is there some "physical" reason? /// You could use events to find the intersections with 2*pi (and possibly 0). Shift the solution down only in the plot, not in the last value that you use as the first value in the next integration. // Or compute the full solution, reduce its values modulo 2*pi, like `mod([-6:6],1.23)`, and employ the feature that matlabs plot has, afaik, to not plot jumps in the data.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you! but could you please tell me how exactly reduce the values? I need to plot this for clarity and also to clearly see the inter-spike interval.

Comment: As I said, simply do `phi = mod(phi, 2*pi);` on the full solution. The elimination of the vertical lines is a cosmetic issue. I thought there was a simple option, but the best I found is [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559391/plotting-discontinuous-function-in-matlab-octave)

Comment: @LutzLehmann so I should do this?
`
gamma = 1.01;

n=3;

[t, phi] = ode45(@(t,x)gamma-sin(x/n), [0,400], 0);

phi = mod(phi, 2*pi);

plot(t, phi, 'k');

ylim([0 2*pi]);

yticks([0 pi 2*pi]);

yticklabels(["0" "\pi" "2\pi"]);

grid on; grid minor;

title('\itsin(x/n)')
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a plot similar to your first sketch, and based on your code in the comments (in future, put such additions into the question itself, use formatting to mark it as addition, and cite it then in the comment) with the changes

- use `pi` as initial point as seen in the drawing,
- use the options of the ODE solver to restrict the step size, directly and by imposing error tolerances
- your original time span covers about 3 periods, reduce this to `[0, 200]` to get the same features as the drawing.

```matlab
gamma = 1.01; n=3; 

opts = odeset('AbsTol',1e-6,'RelTol',1e-9,'MaxStep',0.1); 
[t, phi] = ode45(@(t,x)gamma-sin(x/n), [0,200], pi, opts); 

phi = mod(phi, 2*pi); 

plot(t, phi, 'k'); 
ylim([0 2*pi]); yticks([0 pi 2*pi]); yticklabels(["0" "\pi" "2\pi"]); 
grid on; grid minor; 
title('\itsin(x/n)')
```

To get more elaborate, use events to get points on the numerical solution where it exactly crosses the `2*pi` periods, then use that to segment the solution plot (styling left out)

```
function [ res, term, dir ] = event(t,y)
    y = mod(y+pi,2*pi)-pi;
    res = [ y ]; 
    dir = [1]; % only crossing upwards
    term = [0]; % do not terminate
end%function

opts = odeset(opts,'Events',@(t,y)event(t,y));

sol = ode45(@(t,x)gamma-sin(x/n), [0,200], pi, opts); 

tfs = [ sol.xe; sol.x(end) ]
N = length(tfs)
clf;
t0 = 0;
for i=1:N
    tf = tfs(i);
    t = linspace(t0+1e-2,tf-1e-2,150);
    y = deval(sol,t);  % octave: deval=@(res,t) interp1(res.x, res.y,t)
    y = mod(y,2*pi); 
    plot(t, y);
    hold on; 
    t0=tf;
end;
hold off;
```

[image]